Google authentication not visible on mobile devices
Well, basically I'm working on a login for an access control I'm working on so I ended up with Google API, and since I'm new to this I have had a lot of troubles, currently I'm really happy because I got the login to work with Google GSI library and I'm getting the Google accounts data that I need, the problem comes with the UI, because I have a container with this elements:
<div id="btnWrap">
  <!-- Sign In With Google button with HTML data attributes API -->
  <div id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id="here i have my project id"
    data-context="signin"
    data-ux_mode="popup"
    data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
    data-auto_prompt="true"
    data-auto_select="true">
  </div>

  <div class="g_id_signin"
    data-type="icon"
    data-shape="circle"
    data-theme="outline"
    data-text="signin_with"
    data-size="large"
    data-logo_alignment="left">
  </div>
</div>

And when I open this on PC it works just perfect, but when I open it with a mobile device it opens the new popup tab but it is completely blank, and since it's a phone I can't open the console to check the issue, I know there's another way to work with this UI using the redirect UX mode, but it requires a different configuration and I got a lot of errors,
So as a summary, my question is why the following interface is not showing on mobile devices

Well, I was expecting to the UI to work just perfectly on any device.
